# Change Sim serial Number in Android Lollipop(Rooted device)

Tags: android, root, xposed

Hello All I am trying to change my Sim Serial Number in Android Lollipop(Rooted Device) and i have also installed Xposed Framework in my device, now I read on net that i should use DonkeyGuard in order to do that but as DonkeyGuard works only Till Android Kitkat.

Can anyone please tell me any other app or way by which i can change my Sim Serial number.

Please Help me guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can feed fake SSN data to specified apps via the Xposed Module XPrivacy.

[Github](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy)

[Xposed repo](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy)

Comment: i am trying to change imei with sim serial number (iccic=d)  the problem happening is imei is not getting changed only ssn is changing can you please tell me why is this happening.